# Dictionary parsing

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {10: "a", 100: "b", 10000: "c"}
dict2 = {1: "abc", 11: "def", 500: "jk", 4000: "mn"}
```

I want to create a dictionary such that if the key in *dict1* is lower than the key in *dict2*, then  the result gets paired with the value from *dict1*. So my result looks like

```
Result={(a,abc),(b,def),(c,jkl),(c,mn)}
```

I am new to dictionaries and am completely loss. I tried

```
    for key,value in dict1:
       for k,v in dict:
            if k<key:
            result[value]=v
```

It doesn't work . If I convert the dict keys to string, and then use (int) to do comparison, it says too many values to unpack.

More importantly, I think the logic is flawed. Something that is less than 100 is also less than 1000 so it will never get the right value. Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Yes, the logic is flawed. You're going to run in to duplicate key issues... What's your larger goal for this snippet?

Comment: Which key in *dict1* is lower than which key in *dict2*?

Comment: What Brionius said. Dicts are unordered, so there's no obvious way of pairing up the keys.

Comment: i want to pair up dict 1 and dict 2 keys. As long as dict 2 key is smaller than dict 1 key, i want them paired up.

Comment: I want to pair it with the lowest key that is lower than the key in the other dict

Comment: @Illusionist, how does it work when the keys have nothing in common?

Comment: i've done  a bad job of explaining it, but since 1<10, result dict hasan item value pair-> (a,abc). 11<100 so -> (b,def)

Answer (score 1):

The first 3 lines seems okay but then I am not sure, also check your indent on the 4th line. I'd say something like this would work:

```
result = [] #empty list
for key,value in dict1.iteritems():
       for k,v in dict.iteritems():
            if key < k:
                result += (value, v) #the value in the dict result is a tuple, containing both values)
```

Comment: To iterate over a dict's items, as you try to do in both your loops, you need the `.items()` method. E.g.: `for key, value in dict1.items():`. If you don't ask for the items, the naked iteration of dictionaries yields just the sequence of keys.

Comment: this works but how about dupolicate values in dict2?